# Django - AWS S3 - non-predictable behavior when reading a FileField

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a django model like so:

```py
class Segmentation(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(...)
    ...
```

The `file` is an image (of a red blob) that is stored in an AWS bucket.

I am trying to do some simple computer vision logic on each file in my segmentation instances.
However I noticed some very strange non-predictable behavior when reading the file using:

```py
bytes_string = segmentation.file.read()

if bytes_string: 
    # conduct simple cv logic

else: 
    # do nothing
```

Sometimes the file reading "fails" such that `bytes_string` is `b''` and the remaining part of the script does not execute. However, if I rerun the script the file reading may indeed be successful and the remaining part of the script executes as desired.

When exactly a file reading "fails" I have yet to determine. Has anyone come across an issue like this before? The cv-script lives in a `post_save` signal, meaning a solution (ideally) avoids having to repeatedly run this script in order to trigger a successful file-read.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation it turns out the file was already being read previously in a different function. This caused the `read()` method to return nothing as the "read" pointer was already at the end of the file. Adding `segmentation.file.seek(0)` before the second `read()` solved the issue.